# The last statement won't run c#!

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Please help! I ran this program and entered all 3 inputs but the last writeline code wouldn't run and the program just exits itself! I have no idea because I follow the book exactly!

```
        string userName = "";
        int userAge = 0;
        int currentYear = 0;

        Console.Write("Please enter your name: ");
        userName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Please enter your age: ");
        userAge = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please enter the current year: ");
        currentYear = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World! My name is {0} and I am {1} years old. I was born in {2}.", userName, userAge, currentYear - userAge);
```

Comment: add Console.ReadLine() on the end

Comment: It runs, just waaaay too fast. @TimonPost's solution will pause it and you'll be able to see the output

Comment: Or run it from the command line.

Comment: Try the debugger. You'll notice it does run.

Answer (score -3):

at the end of the code add:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```